# Pydantic - Print object on ValidationError and remove from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, pydantic

### Background

I am developing an application which requires a module to validate JSON data. The JSON data provided could have between `500 - 2000` entries. I am unsure if choosing Pydantic is the correct way of achieving the desired outcome (Questions section). Since the application is pretty complicated, I have provided a minimal example.

### Questions

1. When a `ValidationError` is raised by Pydantic, how do I obtain the object with its values? In the example given `{'name': 'FISH', 'is_dry': False, 'price': 3.30}` is an invalid item, but the output only indicates the error and not the object `name \n Item is not part of inventory and is skipped. (type=value_error)`. This is not helpful when trying to determine which items has failed the validation. Additionally, I aim to log object information for future referencing.
2. Does Pydantic provide the functionality to obtain valid and invalid items? As per my example, I have to manually append valid items to a separate list.

   **Valid items**

   ```
   [
       Food(name='XA_APPLE', is_dry=True, price=0.3),
       Food(name='XA_RICE', is_dry=True, price=0.5)
   ]
   ```

   **Invalid items**

   ```
   [
       Food(name='FISH', is_dry=False, price=3.30),
       Food(name='FISH', is_dry=False, price=3.30)
   ]
   ```
3. Would there be a more pythonic way to rewrite this code using list comprehension with the try block?

   ```py
   # The following statement uses list comprehension but
   # stops executing when an exception is raise as there
   # is no try block to catch the exception.
   # foods = [Food(**food) for food in foods]

   # Hence, I resulted in using the following piece of code.
   for food in foods:

       try:
           valid_foods.append(Food(**food))

       except pydantic.ValidationError as err:
           print(err, '-'* 30, sep='\n', end='\n')
   ```

### Code

**Imports**

```py
import pydantic
```

**Pydantic model with validator**

```py
class Food(pydantic.BaseModel):

    name: str
    is_dry: bool
    price: float

    @pydantic.validator('name')
    def validate_name(cls, value: str) -> str:

        if not value.startswith('XA_'):
            raise ValueError('Item is not part of inventory and is skipped.')

        return value
```

**Load values and validate**

```py
# List is to simulate a loaded JSON structure.
foods = [
    {'name': 'XA_APPLE', 'is_dry': True, 'price': 0.30},
    {'name': 'FISH', 'is_dry': False, 'price': 3.30},
    {'name': 'XA_RICE', 'is_dry': True, 'price': 0.50},
    {'name': 'FISH', 'is_dry': False, 'price': 3.30},
]

valid_foods = []

for food in foods:

    try:
        valid_foods.append(Food(**food))

    except pydantic.ValidationError as err:
        print(err, '-'* 30, sep='\n')

print(valid_foods, '-'* 30, sep='\n')
```

### Output

```
1 validation error for Food
name
  Item is not part of inventory and is skipped. (type=value_error)
------------------------------
1 validation error for Food
name
  Item is not part of inventory and is skipped. (type=value_error)
------------------------------
[Food(name='XA_APPLE', is_dry=True, price=0.3), Food(name='XA_RICE', is_dry=True, price=0.5)]
------------------------------
```

Comment: How about: `for food in foods: try: valid_foods.append(Food(**food)) except pydantic.ValidationError as err: invalid_foods.append((food, err))`?

Comment: Note that `end='\n'` is already the default for `print( )`, so you don't need to specify the `end` optional argument.

Comment: @Stef thanks, if there is no solution I would probably have to use the method you provided. Also, I edited the print statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need an additional model:

```
class Foods(BaseModel):

    foods: list[Food]

    @validator('foods', each_item=True)
    def validator_logic(cls, v):
        if v.name.startswith('XA_'):
            return v
        else:
            log.error({'invalid': v})
```

Pydantic allows [recursive models](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#recursive-models) and validators allow validation per item passing the argument `each_item`, so:

1. You could use the above validator block code where invalid itens are logged.
2. I'm unaware of some method to set valid/invalids, I believe you must implement by yourself
3. No need for that using the model above.

Comment: Tried running your code but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @RaymondC. what's the error?

Comment: Because foods is a list `v.startswith` is causing an error. Do I need to do `v.name.startswith`?

Comment: @RaymondC. Yes, because the `v` is a `Food` instance.